# Meteor not running showing issue with node-fiber

Tags: meteor, node-fibers

I have a meteor project. It was running two days before. Now I am getting the following error.

```
## There is an issue with `node-fibers` ##
W20181017-19:00:42.197(7)? (STDERR) 
D:\Work\store\node_modules\fibers\bin\win32-x64-57\fibers.node`    
  is missing.
 (STDERR) Try running this to fix the issue: 
C:\Users\mritu\AppData\Local\.met
 eor\packages\meteor-tool\1.6.0_1\mt-os.windows.x86_64\dev_bundle\bin\node.exe 
D:\Work\store\node_modules
 \fibers/build
W20181017-19:00:42.199(7)? (STDERR) 
D:\Work\store\node_modules\fibers\fibers.js:20
 W20181017-19:00:42.199(7)? (STDERR)     throw new Error('Missing binary. See 
 message above.');
 W20181017-19:00:42.199(7)? (STDERR)     ^
 W20181017-19:00:42.199(7)? (STDERR)
 W20181017-19:00:42.200(7)? (STDERR) Error: Missing binary. See message above.
 W20181017-19:00:42.200(7)? (STDERR)     at Object.<anonymous> 
      (D:\Work\store\node_modules\fibers\fibers.
                                  js:20:8)
 W20181017-19:00:42.200(7)? (STDERR)     at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
 W20181017-19:00:42.201(7)? (STDERR)     at Object.Module._extensions..js
```

My package.json is

```
{
 "name": "frontstore",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
  "babel-runtime": "^6.23.0",
  "bcrypt": "^1.0.2",
  "fibers": "^1.0.15",
"jquery": "^2.2.4",
"lodash": "^4.17.3",
"mailchimp-api-v3": "^1.7.0",
"md5": "^2.2.1",
"meteor-node-stubs": "~0.2.0",
"meteor-react-autoform": "^0.3.0",
"mobile-detect": "^1.3.5",
"moment": "*",
"moment-range": "^2.2.0",
"omise": "^0.5.3",
"prop-types": "^15.5.8",
"react": "^15.3.1",
"react-addons-css-transition-group": "^15.4.2",
"react-addons-pure-render-mixin": "^15.3.2",
"react-bootstrap": "^0.30.3",
"react-burger-menu": "^1.10.9",
"react-date-range": "github:bchurunway/datepicker",
"react-day-picker": "^2.5.0",
"react-dom": "^15.3.1",
"react-helmet": "^5.2.0",
"react-html-parser": "^1.0.3",
"react-infinite-scroll-component": "^2.2.2",
"react-lazy-load": "^3.0.11",
"react-lazyload": "^2.2.7",
"react-loading": "0.0.9",
"react-mounter": "github:bchurunway/react-mounter",
"react-notification-system": "^0.2.11",
"react-number-format": "^1.0.0",
"react-player": "^0.14.3",
"react-radio-group": "^3.0.1",
"react-select": "^2.0.0",
"react-share": "^1.12.1",
"react-slick": "0.14.5",
"react-stars": "^2.2.5",
"react-structured-data": "^0.0.7",
"react-tooltip": "^3.2.7",
"simpl-schema": "^1.4.1",
"twix": "^1.2.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.23.0",
   "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.22.0"
 }
 }
```

My meteor version is 1.6.1. I have tried many ways like deleting node_modules and install it again, delete local folder from meteor and regain it again using meteor command. But nothing works.

Comment: " It was running two days before. " -> Something happened in those two days? Any updates of Meteor or your Windows?

Comment: I have update meteor but that did not help so I update my windows